# facebook openid how to use

Tags: facebook, openid

i googled but nothing found what king of url i must use to init facebook openid? for example google has https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id but what is openid url of facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't use OpenID, it uses OAuth. Detailed information on how to use it you can find here -> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/